# How could I debug Spring Boot repository with H2 in memory database?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, h2, spring-repositories

I am working on Spring Boot and trying to use H2 database (in memory) for my unit tests. My Spring Data repository implementation is not working and I need help in debugging it.

I have reduced my project (not using the original project) to the following example to isolate and demonstrate the problem. The project can be found in [GitHub](https://github.com/pnatsiavas/Foo-project).

Eclipse project structure:

[image: project structure]

pom.xml:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-model</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
        <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

application.properties:

```
debug=true

logging.level.root=WARN
logging.level.org.foo=WARN
logging.level.org.springframework=WARN

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test_database;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
```

Main configuration class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "org.foo.repositories")
@EntityScan("org.foo.entities")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Application {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        logger.info("Application started");
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(ApplicationContext ctx) {
        return args -> {

            logger.trace("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:");
            String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
            Arrays.sort(beanNames);
            for (String beanName : beanNames) {
                logger.trace(beanName);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Student entity class:

```
package org.foo.entities;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Data
public class Student {

    @Id
    private long id;

    private String first_name;

    private String last_name;

}
```

StudentRepository class:

```
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {
    @Override
    List<Student> findAll();
}
```

StudentRepositoryTester class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { org.foo.Application.class }, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class StudentRepositoryTester {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StudentRepositoryTester.class);

    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository studentRepository;

    @Test
    public void findAllTester() {
        Iterable<Student> students = studentRepository.findAll();
        for(Student student: students) {
            logger.info(student.toString());
        }
        long size = StreamSupport.stream(students.spliterator(), false).count();
        assertTrue(students != null && size == 3);
    }

}
```

data.sql:

```
USE `test_database`;

INSERT INTO `students` (`id`,`first_name`,`last_name`) VALUES (1,'First1','Last1');
INSERT INTO `students` (`id`,`first_name`,`last_name`) VALUES (2,'First2','Last2');
INSERT INTO `students` (`id`,`first_name`,`last_name`) VALUES (3,'First3','Last3');
```

schema.sql:

```
DROP ALL OBJECTS; 

CREATE SCHEMA `test_database`;
USE `test_database`;

CREATE TABLE `students` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

I can see in the console log that H2 is populated as I can see the statements in data.sql executed. I see nothing else suspicious in the log.

**Specific questions:**

1. Running StudentRepositoryTester test class, I see (with breakpoint on the assert statement) that no entities are returned. I cannot understand why. Perhaps I miss something in the Spring Boot configuration annotations?
2. I tried to check the database content in the breakpoint, but I cannot find a way to explore the H2 database. I follow [this tutorial](http://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-and-h2-in-memory-database) to open a web explorer application of H2 but nothing is served in localhost:8080. Am I doing something wrong? Alternatively, is there another way to debug what is going on in the H2 database (in memory)?

Please note that the respective Eclipse project has been uploaded in [GitHub](https://github.com/pnatsiavas/Foo-project) to facilitate discussion.

Comment: You are trying very hard NOT to use Spring Boot. Start by cleaning up your `Application`. Remove all annotation and leave only `@SpringBootAplication` everything else is applied by Spring Boot. Remove the `findAll` from `StudentRepository` Spring Data JPA already contains that method. Then cleanup your test remove all annotations and leave only `@SpringBootTest` and `@RunWith` then try again.

Comment: @M.Deinum: Thank you very much for your remarks. I am new to Spring (obviously) and I followed tutorials that suggested using these annotations. I followed your instructions and still I get the same result. No entities returned.

Comment: Did you really do everything I said...Especially the reduction of annotations on the test class?!

Comment: @M.Deinum: Yes. I removed Transactional and ContextConfiguration. I left the rest. Please also note that now, in my log I cannot see the INSERT statements running. I can only see 
drop table student if exists
create table student (id bigint not null, first_name varchar(255), last_name varchar(255), primary key (id))

Comment: You should also set JPA to NOT manage your schema. This is on by default. `spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false` else it will default to `true` for in-memory DBs.

Comment: @M.Deinum: No difference. Not that I can identify at least. The log seems the same... Note that again I cannot see the INSERT statements running. I can only see DROP statements...

Comment: As stated make sure hibernate isn't managing your schema!... The statements you are seeing are from hibernate NOT from your `schema.sql`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180863/discussion-between-pantelis-natsiavas-and-m-deinum).

Answer (score 5):

Turn on logging of SQL statements executed by Hibernate (in application.properties):

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
```

This will output all the SQL statements to the console. But without variables injected. This should help you with troubleshooting.

Answer (score 4):

H2 bootstrap scripts are handled by [ScriptUtils](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/init/ScriptUtils.html)

Therefore, increase it's logging level in application.properties:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils=DEBUG
```